# While restarting eos local node, I'm facing this error?

Tags: nodeos

[image: Error]

What can I do to not lose the data ?

Comment: Please use text error messages. And give a little information about your setup? OS? Startup parameters etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replay blockchain.

```
$ nodeos --replay-blockchain
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, stop nodeos and run with `--hard-replay-blockchain` option.

Comment: I tried both. I'm getting above error after --hard-replay-blockchain

Comment: Delete data/blocks/reversible and data/state directory completely and try again. Be careful not to delete data/blocks/blocks.log.

Comment: I did this. But I ended up losing most of the data. :(

Comment: You cannot lose data unless you delete blocks.log. Transactions are stored in blocks.log and state (including accounts, permission, multi-index table etc.) is built by accumulating changes caused by transactions and it can always be restored by replay. If you lose data, you must do something wrong.

Comment: I deleted only the reversible folder. Is it possible that my most of the data was in that ?

Comment: Did you construct multi-BP private network? A block followed by about 180 blocks becomes irreversible, but if you make multi-BP settings but a certain of them was offline, confirming irreversibility can't be processed normally.

Comment: No. I have a Local single node testnet.

Comment: Interesting. In single node local testnet setup, blocks become irreversible immediately.

Comment: That's what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Actually i have setted up the classic synchronisation of the testnode(jungle testnet). Blocks are receiving from the start. so it was consuming more time and i left the system to sync but the system got turned off when i tried to restart it from where i lefted it showed some kind of no existing state and fork databse error. so i tried to settup the node using snapshot (latest) but it didnt worked too. i have used the replay blocks plugin . not worked . please help..

Comment: Setting up using snapshot is the best way to go. Please check that your snapshot is not corrupted.